# How to use customise DNS along with cluster.local for kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, coredns

How can we use customized internal DNS for services and Pods? i.e along with `cluster.local` I wished to use `my-domain.local`.

For example, both `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` and `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.my-doamin.local` need to be resolved to same.

Comment: Stub domains: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/

Answer (score 1):

You can not add your custom domain like that but you can use ingress to route traffic from your domain to the services using name based virtual hosting.

```
foo.bar.com --|                 |-> foo.bar.com service1:80
              | 178.91.123.132  |
bar.foo.com --|                 |-> bar.foo.com service2:80
```

https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#name-based-virtual-hosting